# Ajax Add Some of Path in URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this bit of ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/bag/NofityEmailExists",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        error: function () {
            XHRCount--;
            return false;
        },
```

I need to pass some of my path after my domain into the url but this is country specific. Currently it is just setting the url as **test.com/bag/NofityEmailExists** but I need to set it as **test.com/GB/bag/NotifyEmailExists** but my website allows me to pick different countries so it isnt always **GB** it could be **DE US** etc...

the ajax works if I hard code the GB onto the url and im on the GB page for example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/GB/bag/NofityEmailExists",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        error: function () {
            XHRCount--;
            return false;
        },
```

this works but obviously I cant do this because it isnt always **GB**. Is there anyway I can add this to my url and it doesnt matter which country I have selected.

Comment: Just append it to the string?

Comment: @Liam I dont know How to get the country code, I was wondering if it was possible to grab it from the url itself

Comment: Well we can't tell you how you specify your own country code...

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "/" + countryCode + "/bag/NofityEmailExists"
```

where countryCode is a variable assigned with "GB", "DE" etc

Comment: Im not sure how to get the country code thats the problem

Comment: That is a problem with your application. How can we help with that? Where is it defined?